# form:Transparent, Control on form:non Transparent?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

How can change alphablend of a form without affect on control in form?

Delphi XE7

[image]

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with Form alphablending. The only solution I know is to make a copy of the background, change it and paint it onto your form to make it look like it is semi-transparent.

Comment: I have done something like this before using two Forms.  One Form on top with the non-alphablend controls with transparency used for all of the background.  This was then displayed in a fixed relative position with the other form which was alphablended.  Unfortunately I don't think I have the code anymore but you may find this an effective approach.

Comment: If you are searching for something like this http://imgur.com/8ImgFIO it would be very broad to make up an answer since it's a combination of layered windows, with own components calling back to paint on the layered bitmap other forms using regions, placed in Move(var Message: TWMMove) of the mainform.

Comment: this link (imgur.com/8ImgFIO) not relevant to my issue. please look top picture! thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem is to use `Multi-Device Application` (if using `VCL` is not possible).

If you need to leave a transparent `TForm` just changing a property `Transparency = True`.

If you need to leave a semi-transparent component, all components have the `Opacity` property that can be assigned a more transparent value between 0 and 1, where 0 is closer to that component.

For example you could put the controls within a `TLayout` and change the `Opacity` of it as you see fit, and have no effect on the other components, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer to this might be pretty simple...(for windows only)

The JEDI VCL library has a component (TJvTransparentForm) that allows you to take an Alpha blended PNG image (ie the gray background shown in your picture above) and use it to make a form control.  The picture is actually stored in a TImage and you would need to place your "Icons" on the image itself.  Then just respond to the mouse clicks on the TImage.

You have what your asking for (maybe?).

If you were tricky enough you could probably even track the mouse movement and change the Image to glow the correct "button" that the mouse was over.