# Lazarus/Codetyphon/freepascal translucent window

Tags: transparency, lazarus, freepascal, codetyphon

I have seen this : [form:Transparent, Control on form:non Transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139855/formtransparent-control-on-formnon-transparent)

I would like to create a translucent window on linux, where the window background has an alpha value of, say, 100, but all components on top of it have full opacity.

This shouldnt be a splash screen. The window borders should exist, and the window should be resizable, draggable.

I dont see any option for doing that in Linux. there is only form alpha-blend, which forces everything to the same opacity.

Please note, that I would like to do this with QT-bindings, as opposed to GTK-bindings, if possible. 
Help please.